# Марс планета и марс - смотровая площадка

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Как мы знаем, Марс - это планета Солнечной системы, названная в честь бога войны древних римлян. Но одновременно марс - это смотровая площадка на мачте парусного корабля, а соответственно, вперед смотрящий назывался марсовым.
Есть ли связь между этими словами? Или же в корабельном случае "марс" - как и большинство терминов, голландского происхождения?

Answer (score 1):

Они не могут быть родственниками. Даже пишутся по-иностранному по-разному. )))

Корабельный марс конечно же голландец. От mars - тем же значением. Связано, видимо с французским маrs (марш, движение)

Ну а бог Марс - он имя собственное, корни теряются в глубине веков.